# Error when filtering after attempting to create an array in Excel with vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm attempting to take a list of names and filter another list based on whether these names appear.  To do so, I want to create an array of the names and then take this array to apply an autofilter to the other sheet from a specific column.  Here's the code I currently have:

```
Dim AdvisorEINs As Variant

    AdvisorEINs = Worksheets("Names to Filter").Range("A1:A36").Value
    Worksheets("All Advisors").Range("$A$1:$DZ$2216").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=AdvisorEINs.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Currently this is returning `Run-time error '424': Object required` when attempting to run and debugging is highlighting the filtering line.  I've added in a `Debug.Print` on the AdvisorEINs variable, which outputs the same error message and suggests to me that this is due to variable not picking up data correctly.  I'm not certain how to have the array pick up the data any other way - is someone able to advise on this?

Comment: `AdvisorEINs` is an array of values. `Criteria1:=AdvisorEINs.Value` treats it like a range. So there is a datatype error in this assignment. It should be `Criteria1:=AdvisorEINs`. But beyond that, shouldn't Criteria1 be a single value? Is it possible to assign an array to it?

Comment: @Variatus, yes, provided you specify `Operator:=xlFilterValues`, as OP's doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to

- use `AdvisorEINs` instead of `AdvisorEINs.Value`
- transpose the array
  , because the `Value` property of a multicell range returns a 2D array (though with one column only... )

like follows:

```
Dim AdvisorEINs As Variant

AdvisorEINs = Worksheets("Names to Filter").Range("A1:A36").Value
Worksheets("All Advisors").Range("$A$1:$DZ$2216").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(AdvisorEINs), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```